# Mule Magento Cloud Connector 2.0, Missing transformer?

Tags: magento-1.7, mule

EDIT: Solved. At the time of asking this question, the Magento Cloud Connector is/was too old to work with Magento 1.7.

---

I'm trying to do a product update using the magento cloud connector. My xml looks as follows:

```
<magento:update-product config-ref="testConfig" doc:name="Update Product" productSku="#[header:OUTBOUND:ProductId]">
    <magento:catalog-product-entity name="#[header:outbound:Name]">
    </magento:catalog-product-entity>
    <magento:additional-attributes>
        <magento:additional-attribute key="isbn" value-ref="#[header:OUTBOUND:ISBN]" />
        <magento:additional-attribute key="subject" value-ref="#[header:OUTBOUND:Subject]" />    
    </magento:additional-attributes>        
</magento:update-product>
```

Trying to do the update always results in the following exception:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=com.magento.api.AssociativeEntity, mimeType='*/*'}".
```

Full stacktrace:

```
ERROR 2013-05-02 09:28:37,056 [[asdasd].httpConnector.receiver.05] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=com.magento.api.AssociativeEntity, mimeType='*/*'}".
Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-236
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=com.magento.api.AssociativeEntity, mimeType='*/*'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper:252 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)

 ********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=com.magento.api.AssociativeEntity, mimeType='*/*'}".
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupTransformer(MuleRegistryHelper.java:252)
    at org.mule.module.magento.processors.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.transform(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:329)
    at org.mule.module.magento.processors.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAndTransform(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:202)
    at org.mule.module.magento.processors.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateAndTransform(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:169)
    at org.mule.module.magento.processors.UpdateProductMessageProcessor.process(UpdateProductMessageProcessor.java:171)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:101)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:112)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$1.process(Flow.java:74)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$1.process(Flow.java:69)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:63)
    at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:3...
********************************************************************************
```

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:magento="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento/1.1/mule-magento.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <magento:config name="testConfig" username="username" password="password" address="wsdllocation" doc:name="Magento"/>  




    <flow name="push-products-to-magentoFlow1" doc:name="push-products-to-magentoFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="20008"  doc:name="HTTP" path="productsToMagento"/>

        <logger level="INFO" message="'#[header:OUTBOUND:ProductId]'" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger level="INFO" message="'#[header:OUTBOUND:Name]'" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <magento:get-product config-ref="testConfig" doc:name="Get Product"  productSku="#[header:OUTBOUND:ProductId]"> 
            <magento:attributes-names>
                 <magento:attributes-name>sku</magento:attributes-name>
            </magento:attributes-names>
        </magento:get-product>

        <logger message="******************* AFTER GET PRODUCT *********************" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <magento:update-product config-ref="testConfig" doc:name="Update Product" productSku="#[header:OUTBOUND:ProductId]">
        <magento:catalog-product-entity name="#[header:outbound:Name]" price="#[header:OUTBOUND:Price]">     
        </magento:catalog-product-entity>
            <magento:additional-attributes><!-- value-ref causes transformer exception? -->
                 <magento:additional-attribute key="isbn" value-ref="#[header:OUTBOUND:ISBN]" />
                 <magento:additional-attribute key="subject" value-ref="#[header:OUTBOUND:Subject]" />  
            </magento:additional-attributes>    
    </magento:update-product>
        <logger message="************** PRODUCT UPDATE SUCCESFULL ************" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>    
    </flow>
</mule>
```

As noted in the comments, I think the problem is around the additional attributes block where it tries to convert a value from string to [AssociativeEntity](http://mulesoft.github.io/magento-connector/java/com/magento/api/AssociativeEntity.html), but fails. I am not quite sure about what the correct syntax for defining additional attributes is, as the [api](http://mulesoft.github.io/magento-connector/mule/magento-config.html#update-product) sample does not have additional attributes defined.

edit:
Changing from value-ref to value solved the transformer problem, but not the underlying problem I had. The connector uses too old wsdl as Masse pointed out below.

Comment: What Mule and Magento connector versions?

Comment: Magento Connector 2.0, mule 3.4CE, magento 1.7

Comment: Thank you: do you mind running Mule with `-M-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true` and post the full stack trace? Also, what else is before/after the `magento:update-product` element?

Comment: I am fairly sure verbose exceptions is on. Before the update product there is a call to getProduct, which works fine. I think that the problem is related to additional attribute part, where it tries to convert the string to AssociativeEntity, which is what magento wants. I'll update the question with full stacktrace tomorrow. The actual problem we have is that only the 'standard' magento attributes are updated, additional attributes are not working. https://github.com/mulesoft/magento-connector/issues/12 This leads me to believe there might be some compability issues as well.

Comment: This is what I was suspecting as well: something upstream in the flow is disturbing `update-product`. Potentially a bug :(

Comment: Oh well, I'll provide the full stacktrace tomorrow, maybe it has some additional information that'd be helpfull.

Comment: @David Dossot I have updated the question with the full stack trace and full xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if in this situation value-ref isn't the correct attribute to use, instead value is ok. This doesn't however solve the situation as the wsdl used in magento-connector is outdated.

The current magento-connector wsdl is magento 1.5 compliant. The wsdl was generated in May 2011, whereas magento modified their wsdl October 2011 by adding single_data field.

So the answer to the real question behind this is that as it is, it can't be done. The magento-connector plugin needs to be updated, magento downgraded or WS-I compliance mode enabled, which has its own drawbacks